# Detect client or server mode

Tags: c#, blazor

I am building a Blazor application which can switch between client mode and server mode. Parts of the application work only in one or the other and need to have fallback code executed in that case.

Is there a good way to check for example if Mono is running or not?

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you solve server/client execution "auto-switch"? [Blazor in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53478760/blazor-in-internet-explorer) Any case with JSInterOp you can ask with script you launched.

Comment: I have a JavaScript solution in place but I would rather have a solution which uses C# only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this can help you:

```
// Mono WebAssembly is running.
if (JSRuntime.Current is MonoWebAssemblyJSRuntime mono)
{
}
else
{
}
```

See also the [instructions about BlazorDualMode](https://github.com/Suchiman/BlazorDualMode) which allows you to run your app in both modes as well as checking which mode is running.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

using [RuntimeInformation.OSDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.osdescription)

```
RuntimeInformation.OSDescription == "web"
```

Answer (score 4):

It's now:

```
RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture == Architecture.Wasm
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the JSRuntime.Current is not reliable given it is null during startup. The following should work at anytime.

`Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null;`

I add this class to the DI Container and thus can drive behavior with it.

```
  public class JsRuntimeLocation
  {
    public bool IsClientSide => HasMono;
    public bool IsServerSide => !HasMono;
    public bool HasMono => Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null;
  }
```

Comment: Nice, I had the problem already and had to place my code in the `App.cshtml` page as a workaround. This is much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This answer was provided by Microsoft [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18268).

`RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Create("WEBASSEMBLY"))`